# query to extract random rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I have the following 2 tables

> Table 1 - Questions 
>   
>   Contains questions and marks allotted for each questions

```
ID| Questions                    | Marks
________________________________________
1 | What is your name?           |  2
2 | How old are you?             |  2
3 | Where are you from?          |  2
4 | What is your father's name?  |  2
5 | Explain about your project?  |  5
6 | How was the training session?|  5
```

> Table 2 - Question Format
>   
>   Contains how many questions (count) to be extracted for a set of Marks

```
Mark  | Count
-------------
  2   |    2
  5   |    1
```

I want the random questions to be picked up from the table [Questions] as per the [count] set in the table [Question_Format].

```
 ID |     Question    
 ----------------------------
 2  |   How old are you?             
 3  |   Where are you from? 
 6  |   How was the training session?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the idea.  Enumerate the questions for each "mark" by using `row_number()`.  Then use this sequential number to select the random questions:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by marks order by newid()) as seqnum
      from questions q
     ) q join 
     marks m
     on q.marks = m.mark and q.seqnum <= m.count;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by Marks order by newid()) as rn
    from Questions
)
select
    q.id, q.Questions
from cte as q
    inner join QuestionFormat as qf on qf.Mark  = q.Marks
where q.rn <= qf.[Count]
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cff8a/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 5):

You could randomly sort the questions (per mark), and then have an non-equality join on table2:

```
SELECT id, question
FROM   (SELECT id, question, marks, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY marks ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
        FROM   questions) q
JOIN   question_format qf ON q.marks = qf.mark AND q.rn <= qf.cnt
```

Comment: `order by rand()` does not do what you expect in SQL Server.  `rand()` is evaluated once per query, so it behaves like a constant.  In an `order by` expression, a constant is non-deterministic (i.e. you don't know what the result will be), but it is not random.  In my experience, it generally produces the data in "read" order.

Comment: Like @Gordon says!  I'll remove downvote if you fix the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for that comment - I was not aware of it. Used `newid()` instead, which IIUC, should do the trick

Comment: @Andomar replaced it with `newid()`, which should solve the issue.